# Use linq to remove elements in one list using a condition in another

Tags: c#, linq

I have

```
List<X> A = new List<X>{null,"1",null,"3"};
List<Y> B = new List<Y>{  0 , 1 ,  2 , 3 };
```

I want to use linq to list only the elemnts in B that have a corresponding value in A that is not null. so...

```
List<Y> C = [some linq expression using A and B];
```

C now has 1 and 3 in it.

How can this be done?

Comment: Need to compare items based on their indices - I don't think LINQ is optimal for this.

Comment: It's not for optimization, its to cut back on for loops. Clean code > fast code in this case.

Comment: So if the indexes are the same, why can't you just have a single for loop and compare indexes? .

Answer (score 4):

```
List<String> A = new List<String> { null, "1", null, "3" };
List<int> B = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3 };

var C = A.Zip(B, (s, n) => new { a = s, b = n })
         .Where(x => x.a != null)
         .Select(x => x.b)
         .ToList();
```

Comment: This answer only works when the two lists are in the same sort order. For example, if your A is {null, "1", "7", null, "3"}, then your result will be: [1, 2]

Comment: @DerekVanCuyk OP [was clear in comments elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007337/use-linq-to-remove-elements-in-one-list-using-a-condition-in-another/44007405?noredirect=1#comment75044010_44007472) that he's joining by *position within the list*, not by value. If it were by value, I agree `Zip` would be a poor way to do a `Join`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var c = B.Where((o, i) => A[i] != null).ToList();
```

Comment: Breaks if arrays aren't same length (A has fewer elements than B) and returns values in B even if A[i] != B[i]!

Comment: @Mardoxx yea, needs some argument validation, but solves the problem. His instructions are unclear on what happens if the values aren't equal, in his case they're of different types anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Edit to note that it was unclear to me when this was written that both lists are aligned by index. Unsure of the value of this response given that information. It's certainly less valuable than I initially imagined.

Essentially what you want is an intersection. Here's an answer using Intersect() that works based on the data and parameters supplied in your example:

```
    var a = new List<string> { null, "1", null, "3" };
    var b = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    var intersection = a.Intersect(b.Select(x => x.ToString())).ToList();
```

You should be able to adapt to an intersection that works for you.

If both of your lists really have nullable items in them, then you'll need additional null checks on the b list (I'm just blindly calling ToString() on each item in it). But there's no reason to filter out nulls in A if B contains no nulls and you are doing an intersection, they will be filtered out as part of that process.

Consider also that:

```
    b.Select(x => x.ToString()) ...
```

Could very easily be:

```
    b.Select(x => ConvertTypeBToTypeA(x)) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> A = new List<string> { null, "1", null, "3" };
List<int> B = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3 };

var C = B.Where(x => A.Contains(x.ToString()));
```

Comment: no that's not what I mean. list A could have: null, "one", null, "three".  I'm just trying to show that they correspond.

Comment: @G.H. If that's the case (and I hope it is, having assumed so in my answer), I urge you to update your question to initialize A with values that make that explicitly clear. `{ null, "foo", null, "bar" }` or some such.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var c = Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Min(B.Count, A.Count))
                  .Where(i => A[i] != null)
                  .Select(i => B[i]).ToList();
```

Comment: Interesting, but I think it does a lot of unnecessary work. Since the range is from `0` to `Math.Min(B.Count, A.Count)`-1 it shouldn't be possible for `i` to ever be `>=` either `A.Count` or `B.Count`. Still does indexing which is inefficient for `List<>`

Comment: @NetMage agreed, edited to accommodate your comment.

Answer (score 0):

How about an extension method to avoid some overhead?

```
public static class Ext {
    public static IEnumerable<T1> WhereOther<T1, T2>(this IEnumerable<T1> src, IEnumerable<T2> filter, Func<T2, bool> pred) {
        using (var isrc = src.GetEnumerator())
        using (var ifilter = filter.GetEnumerator())
            while (ifilter.MoveNext())
                if (isrc.MoveNext())
                    if (pred(ifilter.Current))
                        yield return isrc.Current;

    }
}
```

With that created, you can use

```
var ans = B.WhereOther(A, p => p != null);
```

You may also want an `IQueryable` variant, though creating one isn't that easy.
I guess you could cheat and return a lambda that applies `AsEnumerable()` and then uses `IEnumerable.WhereOther`.